# How can I create a desktop icon with a custom context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop, icons, context-menu

Before when I used Windows XP I had a program (it is called SCCU but I am not sure where I got it from) that allowed you to create an icon on the desktop with a completely custom context menu, now that I am running Windows 7 it does not work so well anymore.

You would choose an icon and then you could add and remove items to the context menu, the context menu also didn't have any of the default Windows context menu items such as Open, Delete, etc.

I have found many discussions about adding context menu items to existing file types but nothing about what I want to do; Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an updated version that works with Windows 7, it can be found here:
http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/224324-desktop-icons-without-text/page-54

It works well when creating desktop icons, but unfortunately if you pin the icon to the start menu the custom context menu items no longer work.
I have however found another program that allows you to create custom jump lists in Windows 7, you can find the program here: http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/